# Route traffic with consistent hashing on low-load pods with Istio

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, istio, servicemesh, linkerd

We want to use Istio to setup Websocket connections to our pods in EKS based on the URL. This should be done via consistent hashing.

That would likely not pose to much problems to us.

However, we only want to do the hashing on pods with a "not too high" load.

Is such a thing possible with Istio? If so, could you share some examples as we are currently not very familiar with Istio.